# "What is inevitable is the catastrophic..."

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, cleft-constructions

Is the sentence below structurally correct, if not please rectify it. Furthermore, I would really appreciate it if you could also say whether it is a cleft sentence or not, and how to make the sentence of higher quality.

> What is inevitable is the catastrophic effects coronavirus has led to.

Comment: [What is inevitable are the etc.]

Comment: This is a particular type of cleft sentence called a wh-cleft or a pseudo-cleft sentence. https://www.grammaring.com/pseudo-cleft-sentences  Many would put “the” before coronavirus in this sentence, and as Lambie has noted above, the second “is” should be “are.” (The simple version of the sentence is “the catastrophic effects [the] coronavirus has led to are inevitable”.)